# Implementing RESTful API in node.js

Tags: node.js, rest

I have the following hypothetical RESTful API endpoints:

```
/courses
/courses/:id
/students
/students/:id
/courses/:c_id/students
/courses/:c_id/students/:s_id
/students/:s_id/courses
/students/:s_id/courses/:c_id
```

How would you code the routes in node.js (I use express) so that you have less repetition of code and routes (especially in the many-to-many relationship of students and courses)?

An example brute force approach would be:

```
app.get('/courses', courses.getAll);
app.post('/courses', courses.create);
app.get('/courses/:id', courses.get);
app.put('/courses/:id', courses.edit);
app.del('/courses/:id', courses.delete);
...
app.get('/courses/:c_id/students', courseStudents.getStudents);
app.get('/courses/:c_id/students/:s_id', courseStudents.getStudent);
...
app.get('/students/:s_id/courses', studentCourses.getCourses)
app.get('/students/:s_id/courses/:c_id', studentCourses.getCourse)
...
```

Comment: I am not very familiar with express...but, I would assume you'd have one "main server" with a switch statement for the method and some regex to handle the different rest endpoints. Just a though.

Comment: Why are you trying to flip the students and courses in both directions? What is the point of that?

Comment: I see your point in the case of /courses/:c_id/students/:s_id and /students/:s_id/courses/:c_id. Nevertheless, i want to get a list of students enrolled in a course(/courses/:c_id/students) and a list of courses a student is enrolled in(/students/:s_id/courses)

Comment: Check out [`express-resource`](https://github.com/visionmedia/express-resource).

Comment: Check out [restpress](https://github.com/palanik/restpress) #plug

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to try [loopback](http://loopback.io/), it is based on express.js and is designed for REST APIs.

Here an example: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-full-stack